# Copy only htm not html files batch windows

Tags: batch-file, copy

I created a windows batch file to copy only files with specific extensions into a different folder. Here is the line of code I used:

```
for /R "%cd%" %%f in (*.htm) do copy "%%f" "%cd%\myfolder"
```

The issue is that this will copy any extension that starts with .htm, i.e. .html, which I do not want; only .htm. How is this copy prevented?

I've tried

```
"(*.htm)"
("*.htm")
(*".htm")
(*."htm")
(*.htm*)
```

Thanks

**Solution:**

```
for /R %%f in (*.htm) do if /I "%%~xf" == ".htm" copy "%%f" "myfolder"
```

Thanks @Aacini and @Monacraft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
for /R %%f in (*.htm) do if /I "%%~xf" == ".htm" copy "%%f" "myfolder"
```

A couple comments unrelated to your problem:

- `%cd%` is a variable that is always replaced by *the current folder*. If you give any name without a previous path, the name is assumed to be *in the current folder*. This way `name` and `%cd%\name` is exactly the same and the second one is customarily never used.
- In `for /R [path] %%f ...` command, if the path is not given, the current folder is assumed.

Answer (score 2):

You could check using an `if` statement:

```
for /R "%cd%" %%f in (*.*) do if /i "%%~xf"==".htm" copy "%%f" "%cd%\myfolder"
```

And that is the logical way to do this in batch.

Mona

Comment: @foxidrive: If you review the question, the OP already tested this solution _in its original form_ and reported it not worked. The changes you introduced makes this solution practically equal than the mine, although the mine was posted 2 hours after this one. I just wanted to make clear this point...

Comment: @aacini Your solution improves on Mona's by clarifying the `%cd%` points.  Mona's solution was missing the case insensitive switch and so would fail in many cases - I merely improved that issue.  I upvoted your solution.

Comment: The case insensitive portion was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `*.htm` matches `.html` files is because of short 8.3 file names. A file with `.html` extension will have a short name with `.htm` extension.

Monacraft and Aacini have provided working solutions using IF statemnts within the body of the loop.

Here is a solution that uses DIR /B piped to FINDSTR within a FOR /F IN() clause.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s /a-d-h-s *.html ^| findstr /lie .htm') do copy "%%F" "myfolder"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way, but `(*.ht?)` should do it.

Comment: This matches both short and long filename so doesn't work to solve this issue.

Comment: My understanding of the `?` wildcard was that it looks for a match of only 1 character as opposed to the `*` wildcard. For instance `file?` would match `file1` or `files` but not `filename`. Is that not correct?

Comment: `DIR` and `FOR` etc match `BOTH` the short filename AND the long filename.  In this case the short filename extension for `a.html` is `.htm` and your filespec will match it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a windows vista or later OS, you can use robocopy and exclude not needed files

```
robocopy "%cd%" "%cd%\myFolder" *.htm /xf *.html
```